# Extracting words separated by special sign (regex)

Tags: regex, r

I have some sting like `"John a11|a12|\n  Ana a21|a22|\n  Jake a31|a23|\n   "`
I would like to extract all parts seperated by `"|"` using regex.

So I want the output

`"John a11" "a12" "Ana a21" "a22" "Jake a31" "a23"`

And ideas how to create proper regex or maybe it requires just some function in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `strsplit()` with the split regular expression `"[\\||\n] *"`:

```
x <- "John a11|a12|\n  Ana a21|a22|\n  Jake a31|a23|\n   "

strsplit(x, split="[\\||\n] *")[[1]]
[1] "John a11" "a12"      ""         "Ana a21"  "a22"      ""         "Jake a31" "a23"      ""
```

Comment: For the exact desired result: `strsplit(x, "[|]|(\\|\n )")[[1]]`

Comment: Even more accurater: `strsplit(x, " *[|]|(\\|\n ) *")[[1]]`

Answer (score 3):

You can split on `|` and make the newline sequence optional followed by "zero or more" spaces.

```
x <- 'John a11|a12|\n Ana a21|a22|\n Jake a31|a23|\n  '
strsplit(x, '\\|\n? *')[[1]]
# [1] "John a11" "a12"      "Ana a21"  "a22"      "Jake a31" "a23"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.

```
x <- "John a11|a12|\n  Ana a21|a22|\n  Jake a31|a23|\n   "

library(rex)    
re_matches(x,
  rex(
      any_spaces,
      capture(name = 'text',
        except_some_of("|")
      ),
      any_spaces),
  global = TRUE)[[1]]
#>      text
#>1 John a11
#>2      a12
#>3  Ana a21
#>4      a22
#>5 Jake a31
#>6      a23
#>7
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're the author of the `rex` package?